# Client-side data storage - IndexedDB for global data using?

Tags: database, browser, storage, client-side, indexeddb

I was wondering, if data stored in IndexedDB can be used globally by other users? Or it's purpose is only for local usage? For example if I'll do web page with personal notes, can the notes be visible for other users on other computer (if I want them to be?). And how the IndexedDB works. If it's localy stored, then what if the user will uninstall the web browser or just even destroy the computer. Will the data be deleted?
Sorry, if it's silly question for You :D

Answer (score 0):

IndexedDb is browser based storage mechanism. A few reading in the web will give enough information I will try to list of few crux of indexedDB

- It is browser based Data storage mechanism , its scope limited to browser and machine. That means one you stored something to IndexedDB only from that browser and that machine and from same domain only you can access. Domain means if you have a website which useses indexedDb from no other website can be accessed.
- Indexed db can use 6-10% of the hard disk of your machine
- Indexed db data wont be loosed if you closed or rebooted your machine. even Ctrl+f5 wont loose the data. if user do a hard cache delete then the indexed db data will be loosed.
- Check [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/) for the browser compatibility
- IndexedDB basically work of Key value pair data storage, we can do indexing on those itesm, in indexed db we can created multiple store to categorize the data, store concept wise we can relate to table in SQL
- IndexedDB is a way for you to persistently store data inside a user's browser. Because it lets you create web applications with rich query abilities regardless of network availability, these applications can work both online and offline. IndexedDB is useful for applications that store a large amount of data
- IndexedDB is an asynchronous API that can be used in most contexts, including Web Workers. It used to include a synchronous version also, for use in web workers, but this was removed from the spec due to lack of interest by the web community.

more about indexedDB please read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Basic_Concepts_Behind_IndexedDB).